# Backup/Restore ArcGIS Server 10.2.2 site that is federated with Portal 10.2.2

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-portal, data-backup

Is it possible to backup and restore an ArcGIS Server site that is federated with portal using a domain certificate (in other words a certificate that is not CA-signed)?  I am attempting this directly in the REST admin site using the exportSite and importSite operations.  I am receiving the following error:

> "Unable to find valid certification path to requested target."

I am curious if this is even possible, and if so, what steps should I take to get around the issue of using a domain certificate?

Comment: Is the ArcGIS Server Webserver IIS 7.5 or Tomcat7?

Comment: The ArcGIS Server Webserver is IIS 8.5.

Comment: What DB backend Oracle 11g 12c? Portal does support virtualization http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/index.html#/Portal_for_ArcGIS/01510000008p000000/ which can be cloned easily.

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection

Comment: The site I am attempting to restore did have an Oracle 12c database registered to it, if that is what you mean by DB backend.  I do not believe that virtualization is an option for us.  The stackoverflow link seems to be on the right track.  Are you aware of any resources involving Python related to this issue?  Trying to make sense of the Java code and relating it to my scenario is a bit over my head, being the novice programmer I am.

Comment: Python SSL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582766/adding-ssl-support-to-socketserver

Comment: I appreciate the info.  We may look into this route, but I am surprised that ESRI does not offer a solution to this.  I wonder if it is just an assumption that if you require backing up a site, then you will have a CA-signed certificate.

Comment: Try contacting support@esri.com with your customer account  info and your requirements response can be 2-3 days.

Comment: @Mapperz Portal is supported on Virtual environments, from ur link: "All components of Portal for ArcGIS are fully supported on virtual environments as long as they run on supported platforms."